# Resize UITableViewCell with WebViews according to webviews content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I'm trying to have a custom height on a cell depending on the height of webview.

Right now I try to add the frame.size.height of the webview to a NSMutableArray which of course crashes on insertObject (the solution I've tried here is pretty sloppy).

How do I accomplish this?

```
int indexPathIntValue;

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifer = @"PictureCell";

    InspirationFeedCell *cell;
    cell = (InspirationFeedCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifer];
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [mainBundle loadNibNamed:@"PictureCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.feedCell;
        self.feedCell = nil;
    }

    indexPathIntValue = indexPath.row;

    //Here I deleted some code that fetches descriptionWebString

    [cell.feedWebView setDelegate:self];
    [cell.feedWebView loadHTMLString:descriptionWebString baseURL:nil];

    return cell;

}

-(void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    CGRect frame = webView.frame;
    frame.size.height = 1;
    webView.frame = frame;
    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
    frame.size = fittingSize;
    webView.frame = frame;

    int heightOfWebViewInt = frame.size.height;
    [sizeOfWebViewCell insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:heightOfWebViewInt] atIndex:indexPathIntTest];
    DLog(@"numberSizeInValue: %d", heightOfWebViewInt);

    if (!alreadyUpdated) {
        alreadyUpdated = YES;
        [inspirationFeedTable reloadData];
    }
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row < [sizeOfWebViewCell count] && [sizeOfWebViewCell count] != 0) {

        NSNumber *numberValueOfHeight = [sizeOfWebViewCell objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        int rowAtHeight = numberValueOfHeight.integerValue;

        return rowAtHeight;

    }
    return 360;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please set cell.feedWebView.tag = indexPath.row;

instead of  indexPathIntValue = indexPath.row;

And in webViewDidFinishLoading method Please use below line

[sizeOfWebViewCell insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:heightOfWebViewInt] atIndex: webView.tag];

Answer (score 1):

Hi why are you saying:

> which of course crashes on insertObject

Actually it shouldn't crash. Make sure that `sizeOfWebViewCell` is a `NSMutableArray`, use the method `addObject` and check if your instance is allocated and initialized correctly.